# How canI achieve wrap_content behaviour for items inside LazyHorizontalGrid in compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm build a layout in compose that contains a LazyHorizontalGrid with 2 rows of cards, let's say:

```
LazyHorizontalGrid(
    rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(2F) //Workaround that I found to try to limit LazyHorizontalGrid Height
) {
    item(5){
        Card {
            Column {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.item_title))
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.item_image), contentDescription = null )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I Fix it in 2 rows, the LazyHorizontalGrid changes the items height to half of the screen remaining height. In other words, it fills all the remaining height.

I placed a aspect ratio to try to limit the height of my items (by limiting the height of LazyHorizontalGrid itself). There will be other elements below the LazyHorizontalGrid.

How Can I achieve "wrap_content" behaviour for item's height inside LazyHorizontalGrid?

Things I tried:

- Use `GridCells.FixedSize()` - I can't. I need two rows regardless of screen size
- User `verticalArrangement` for `LazyHorizontalGrid` - No difference at all
- Add `Modifier.wrapContentHeight()` at `Card's` composable - No difference at all

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to Implement LazyHorizontalGrid with two rows and you've got to this screen,

[image]

with LazyHorizontalGrid filling the whole page.
To limit the height of each item, set `.wrapContentHeight()` to `Card` which will make the view like,

[image]

And if you're trying to add other elements below the LazyHorizontalGrid, you should wrap the LazyHorizontalGrid within a Container and set `.weight(1f)`. this will make the LazyHorizontalGrid occupy the remaining available space like,

[image]

here's the implementation,

```
    Column {
        LazyHorizontalGrid(
            rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp),
            modifier = modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            (0..10).forEach {
                item(it) {
                    Card(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .padding(10.dp)
                            .wrapContentHeight()
                    ) {
                        Column {
                            Text(
                                modifier = modifier.padding(10.dp),
                                text = "title"
                            )
                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .background(color = Color.Green)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(.5f)
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                text = "other elements below the LazyHorizontalGrid"
            )
        }
    }
```

To just wrap the content height of the LazyHorizontalGrid, you could use `FlowRow`,

```
FlowRow {
            repeat(6) {
                Card(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                ) {
                    Column {
                        Text(
                            modifier = modifier.padding(10.dp),
                            text = "title"
                        )
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]